# How to define a function so that $a<f(n)<b$?

Tags: functions, integers

For a given interval $(a,b)$, whre $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$, is it possible to define a function such that $a<f(n)<b$, for any positive integer $n$.

For example,
$0<\dfrac{n}{2^n}<1$ for all integers $n$($>0$).

**Updated:**
I would like to define $f$ like this way :
$f(n)=\phi(n,a,b)$, where $a,b$ are given in advance and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, i.e., in the definition of $f(n)$, $n$ will present as well as $a,b$.

Comment: I would like to define f(n) in terms of a,b.

Answer (score 4):

You say you need $n$ in the definition. If that's so important to you, you can take $f(n)=\frac {a+b} 2+0\times n$

Comment: it is not the right construction, actually $f(n)=F_{a,b}(n)$ @Martin Argerami.

Comment: You would have to explain exactly what is not "right".

Answer (score 2):

Sure, and you've given the answer right there. As you say $0 < \frac
{n}{2^n} < 1$. Note also that we must have $b \geq a+1$. So, $a < a + \frac{n}{2^n} < a+1 \leq b$. So, given such a pair $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, if you define $f(n) = a + \frac{n}{2^n}$, then it will have that property.

Comment: There are an infinite number of such ways, of course.  A trivial extention:  $f(n) = a + {\alpha \over 2^n}$ for $\alpha <1$.

Comment: @msm, I would like to define $f(n)$ in terms of $a,b$.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by defining it in terms of $a,b$. Could you provide an example of something you consider defined in terms of $a,b$?

Comment: $f(n)$ will contains $a,b$. In your answer $f(n)$ contains only $a$ @mam

Comment: Let $f(n) = a + (b-a) \frac{n}{2^n}$.

Comment: @H.S.:  So make it $f(n)=a+(b-a)\frac n{2^n}$  You seem to have some requirements in your mind that you have not stated, like it is not the same for all $n$ as in Martin Argerami's answer, that it depend on $b$ as in your comment to this one, and what else?  Monotonic with $n$?

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$\forall x:\tanh(x) \in (-1,1)$$
so
$$\frac{b-a}{2}\tanh(x) \in\left(\frac{a-b}{2},\frac{b-a}{2}\right)$$
and
$$\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}\tanh(x) \in \left(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a-b}{2},\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}\right)=\left(a, b\right)$$